# WPF y MVVM with two datagrid, how to change color of some rows in one of them according to condition?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a view with two datagrids. For the question, I use two dataGrid, one with the information of authors and other with information of songs. The first datagrid bind an observableCollection of entity Authors and the second datagrid bind an observableCollection of entity songs.

In both case, I have textbox that I can use to search authors by some criteria and other textBox that let to search for songs.

I would like that if I have selected only a row in the authors datagrid, when I search for songs, I would like that the songs of the author have a different background, for example green.

One example. I have selected the author Elvis Presley and I search for rock songs. I get many songs that there are not of Elvis. So in the datagrid of songs I have all the rock songs, and if the song is of Elvis, the background of the row must have a different color.

Other case, if first I search for songs and later search for authors, if I select only one author in the dataGrid, the background of the songs change if belong this author. And if I select two or more authors or I select nobody, then clear the background in the songs datagrid.

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Comment: Expose a boolan property CurrentAuthor and add logic for that.  Then use a DataTrigger to change the background.   I know just an outline but this was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Another option would be to bind the color to a ViewModel prop, and change it in the VM. This is more flexible (any number of colors/conditions), and keeps the logic out of the view.